# How to correctly display edited file output?

Tags: c, file-io, output

I'm trying to make a character generator/editor and I wanted to make a list of all already saved characters appear on the console screen.

I managed to get the list working but there is a slight problem with output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

void main(){
    CreateDirectory("Characters",NULL);
    CreateDirectory("Characters\\some random name",NULL);
    CreateDirectory("Characters\\another random name",NULL);
    system("dir /b/aD \Characters > character_list.txt");

    FILE *f;

    char Name[50];
    int c, i=1;

    f = fopen("character_list.txt", "r");
        if(f == NULL){
            printf("Could not open character list");
            return;
        }
        printf("Choose character to edit:\n1) ");
        if(f)
            while((c=getc(f)) != EOF){
                if(c=='\n'){
                    putchar(c);
                    printf("%d) ", ++i);
                }
                else putchar(c);
            }
    fclose(f);
    return;
}
```

for two created characters the output looks like this:

```
Choose character to edit:
1) some random name
2) another random name
3)
```

And here's the question. How can I remove the last point so it would look like this?

```
Choose character to edit:
1) some random name
2) another random name
```

Comment: Have you thought of looping with `fgets` to read complete lines from the file instead of checking for a new line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A newline terminates the current line, and it does not mean that further characters will follow. So you get the "empty" `3)` because there is no more character to read after the last new line. 
So I'd introduce a variable that indicates if the counter `%d)` shall be printed *in the next run* (i.e. only if further characters follow):

```
        int beginOfNewLine = 1;
        while((c=getc(f)) != EOF){
            if (beginOfNewLine) {
                printf("%d) ", ++i);
                beginOfNewLine = 0;
            }
            if(c=='\n'){
                beginOfNewLine = 1;  // trigger to print the counter in the next run
            }
            putchar(c);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I remove the last point so it [doesn't write an empty last line]?
>
> ```
>     while((c=getc(f)) != EOF){
>         if(c=='\n'){
>             putchar(c);
>             printf("%d) ", ++i);
>         }
>         else putchar(c);
>     }
> ```

```
    bool emptyline = true;
    while ((c = getc(f)) != EOF) {
        if (emptyline) {
            printf("%d) ", ++i);
            emptyline = false;
        }
        putchar(c);
        if (c == '\n') emptyline = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to use that beautiful char Name [50] of yours ;)

Store the name until you find the '\n', then display it.
This way you'll be able to check for errors before displaying the index :D